# Half of my Foundation6 doesn't work in Angular4

Tags: angular, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

There are certain Foundation 6 elements that work for my Angular App such as the `.button` class but when I tried to make a drop down menu or a navbar it doesn't collapse the drop down menu

```
<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1B</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

But it looks like

### --

[image: Incorrectly formatted code]

### --

I have the following lines in my `.angular-cli.json` file

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation-flex.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/foundation-sites/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js"
  ],
```

My hunch is that the javascript aspect isn't working but I'm not sure how to fix it.

** I went into the NPM folders to make sure that those files that the .angular-cli.json is pointing to does in fact exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking around on different chat channels this is what I learned

> you really should have a wrapper for foundation, im not sure there is
>   one, there is one for bootstrap and theres one for material2. I would
>   start there and look at those components. Foundation doesn't offer any
>   benefits to Angular when it comes to components because they weren't
>   written specifically for angular. You can still pick and choose that
>   pieces you like from the SCSS/ CSS of foundation but you would have to
>   write your own components or use bootstraps and just them it to be
>   like foundation
>   ie: https://material.angular.io/components or
>   https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

- @zurie on Gitter

So as for now I've decided to look into material until I understand more.